# How to use Terraform to disable deletion protection on AWS RDS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I used Terraform to bring up an AWS RDS SQL Server DB with deletion_protection set to true. Now, I am trying to delete the database and hence I tried to first run {terraform apply} with deletion_protection set to false, and I got the following error:

```
Error: error deleting Database Instance "awsworkerdb-green": InvalidParameterCombination: Cannot delete protected DB Instance, please disable deletion protection and try again.
    status code: 400, request id: 7e787deb-af03-4016-9baa-471ab9c0ae1c
```

Then I tried to directly do {terraform destroy} using the same TF code with deletion_protection set to false, I got the following error:

```
Error: error deleting Database Instance "awsworkerdb-green": InvalidParameterCombination: Cannot delete protected DB Instance, please disable deletion protection and try again.
    status code: 400, request id: 9a95ef70-8738-4a31-b0cd-cf10ef05bdec
```

How does one go about deleting this database instance using terraform?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This would be two distinct API invocations, and therefore two consecutive Terraform executions with two different config modifications:

- Modify `deletion_protection` to be `false` in your config, and `apply` your changes to the RDS instance.
- Remove the RDS from the config and `apply`, or `destroy` the RDS resource directly. Either action will delete the RDS instance.

Comment: Thanks Matt! This was helpful. Finally, I was able to do it using the AWS CLI via Terraform.

Answer (score 5):

You can't. You have to do it manually using AWS console or AWS CLI with [modify-db-instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/modify-db-instance.html). The entire point of deletion protection is so that the rds instance is not easy to delete, and you have to explicitly modify it for that.

Comment: Thanks Marcin! I actually used Terraform to run the AWS CLI with modify-db-instance.
You can run the AWS CLI commands using Terraform by using a null_resource as follows:
resource "null_resource" "deleteprotection" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "aws rds modify-db-instance --db-instance-identifier awsworkerdb-green  --no-deletion-protection --region "us-east-1" --apply-immediately"
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

From cli use below

aws rds modify-db-instance --db-instance-identifier <DB_IDENTIFIER> --region <DB_REGION> --no-deletion-protection --apply-immediately

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).